# OpenCV Python rotate image by X degrees around specific point

Tags: python, opencv, rotation

I'm having a hard time finding examples for rotating an image around a specific point by a specific (often very small) angle in Python using OpenCV.

This is what I have so far, but it produces a very strange resulting image, but it is rotated somewhat:

```
def rotateImage( image, angle ):
    if image != None:
        dst_image = cv.CloneImage( image )

        rotate_around = (0,0)
        transl = cv.CreateMat(2, 3, cv.CV_32FC1 )

        matrix = cv.GetRotationMatrix2D( rotate_around, angle, 1.0, transl )
        cv.GetQuadrangleSubPix( image, dst_image, transl )
        cv.GetRectSubPix( dst_image, image, rotate_around )

    return dst_image
```

Answer (score 172):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def rotate_image(image, angle):
  image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
  rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
  result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  return result
```

Assuming you're using the cv2 version, that code finds the center of the image you want to rotate, calculates the transformation matrix and applies to the image.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however I'm using the "cv" module and you are using "cv2", so its complaining specifically about "image.shape" not existing. I have only been using the "cv" module up until now, so I don't quite get all the changes with "cv2" yet. I know my image is (140,140), so I tried hard coding that in place of image.shape, but it didn't like that at all either.

Comment: I think I may have made some progress, but still running into a problem. Here is the latest code:

result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, cv.GetSize(image), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)


Traceback (most recent call last):
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, cv.GetSize(image), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array

Comment: I have a problem running
cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center=image_center ,angle=angle,scale=1)

TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: image.shape include the width,height and channel

Comment: @Hani  try cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((imagecenter[0],imagecenter[1]),angle,1.0)

Comment: This solution changes the image dimensions.  See nicodjimenez's answer below.

Comment: `angle` is in degrees. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=getrotationmatrix#getrotationmatrix2d

Comment: I believe there might be an error in this answer. I think the correct image center to rotate around is off by 0.5 pixel. The correct code would be `image_center = tuple((np.array(image.shape[1::-1])-1) / 2)`. To check this I encourage you to create a small image with a single line in the middle and rotate it with 45 degrees. Like this `im = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3), dtype=np.uint8); im[:, 1] = 1; im_rot = rotate_image(im, 45)`. Using the original code, the line is not correctly rotated, with the adjusted center it is correctly rotated. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Answer (score 81):

Or much easier use
[SciPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/)

```
from scipy import ndimage

#rotation angle in degree
rotated = ndimage.rotate(image_to_rotate, 45)
```

see
[here](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/#id5) 
for more usage info.

Comment: I am looping through a directory of png and doing this but I get a RuntimeError: invalid rotation plane specified. Any fixes?

Comment: do you pass in a open cv image? like from: img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)

Comment: this is quite slow for me

Comment: Nice, it's easier to use and you have an easy way to decide if you want to keep the image size (`reshape=True`) or the image content (`reshape=False`)

Answer (score 23):

```
def rotate(image, angle, center = None, scale = 1.0):
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    if center is None:
        center = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # Perform the rotation
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h))

    return rotated
```

Answer (score 18):

I had issues with some of the above solutions, with getting the correct "bounding_box" or new size of the image. Therefore here is my version

```
def rotation(image, angleInDegrees):
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    img_c = (w / 2, h / 2)

    rot = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(img_c, angleInDegrees, 1)

    rad = math.radians(angleInDegrees)
    sin = math.sin(rad)
    cos = math.cos(rad)
    b_w = int((h * abs(sin)) + (w * abs(cos)))
    b_h = int((h * abs(cos)) + (w * abs(sin)))

    rot[0, 2] += ((b_w / 2) - img_c[0])
    rot[1, 2] += ((b_h / 2) - img_c[1])

    outImg = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot, (b_w, b_h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return outImg
```

Comment: was this for face detection?  I want to rotate video frames by 90 degrees and run MTCNN because it won't detect frontal faces lying sideways (person lying on the ground)

Comment: @mLstudent33 No I used it for a different purpose, but this is just rotating an image. So if you have the angle then it should be fine?

Comment: I think so.  I can rotate, run detection, then draw `cv2.rectangle()` and then rotate it back.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 13):

The cv2.warpAffine function takes the shape parameter in reverse order: (col,row) which the answers above do not mention.  Here is what worked for me:

```
import numpy as np

def rotateImage(image, angle):
    row,col = image.shape
    center=tuple(np.array([row,col])/2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,1.0)
    new_image = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, (col,row))
    return new_image
```

Comment: getRotationMatrix2D seems to require (col,row), too. `center` should use (col,row) as well, as is done in @Omnipresent's answer.

Comment: I agree that it wasn't clear. @alex-rodrigues ' answer does some slicing to the image.shape to get the width and height in the right order for warpAffine:
image.shape[1::-1] does this. What this does is takes a slice starting at the 1st element, with a step value of -1, so proceeding left, so you end up with a slice with [1][0], which is the width (columns), followed by height (rows).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use the `imutils` package to do the  rotation. it has two methods

1. **rotate**: rotate the image at specified angle. however the drawback is image might get cropped if it is not a square image.
2. **rotate_bound**: it overcomes the problem happened with rotate. It adjusts the size of the image accordingly while rotating the image.

more info you can get on this blog:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/01/02/rotate-images-correctly-with-opencv-and-python/

Comment: can I run face detection on the rotated frame?  MTCNN does not detect frontal faces lying sideways.

Answer (score 6):

```
import imutils

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
...

while (1):
   frame = vs.read()
   ...

   frame = imutils.rotate(frame, 45)
```

More: https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils

Comment: this one wont cut any of the image: `imutils.rotate_bound(frame, 90)`

Answer (score 4):

Quick tweak to @alex-rodrigues answer... deals with shape including the number of channels.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def rotateImage(image, angle):
    center=tuple(np.array(image.shape[0:2])/2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center,angle,1.0)
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[0:2],flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a homogenous matrix of size 2x3. First 2x2 is the rotation matrix and last column is a translation vector.

[image]

Here's how to build your transformation matrix:

```py
# Exemple with img center point:
# angle = np.pi/6
# specific_point = np.array(img.shape[:2][::-1])/2

def rotate(img: np.ndarray, angle: float, specific_point: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    warp_mat = np.zeros((2,3))
    cos, sin = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
    warp_mat[:2,:2] = [[cos, -sin],[sin, cos]]
    warp_mat[:2,2] = specific_point - np.matmul(warp_mat[:2,:2], specific_point)
    return cv2.warpAffine(img, warp_mat, img.shape[:2][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rotate the images using opencv python-

```
def funcRotate(degree=0):
    degree = cv2.getTrackbarPos('degree','Frame')
    rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((width / 2, height / 2), degree, 1)
    rotated_image = cv2.warpAffine(original, rotation_matrix, (width, height))
    cv2.imshow('Rotate', rotated_image)
```

If you are thinking of creating a trackbar, then simply create a trackbar using `cv2.createTrackbar()` and the call the `funcRotate()`fucntion from your main script. Then you can easily rotate it to any degree you want. Full details about the implementation can be found here as well- [Rotate images at any degree using Trackbars in opencv](https://www.life2coding.com/how-to-rotate-images-at-any-degree-usingtrackbar-in-opencv-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for rotating about an arbitrary point (x,y) using only openCV

```
def rotate_about_point(x, y, degree, image):
    rot_mtx = cv.getRotationMatrix2D((x, y), angle, 1)
    abs_cos = abs(rot_mtx[0, 0])
    abs_sin = abs(rot_mtx[0, 1])
    rot_wdt = int(frm_hgt * abs_sin + frm_wdt * abs_cos)
    rot_hgt = int(frm_hgt * abs_cos + frm_wdt * abs_sin)
    rot_mtx += np.asarray([[0, 0, -lftmost_x],
                           [0, 0, -topmost_y]])
    rot_img = cv.warpAffine(image, rot_mtx, (rot_wdt, rot_hgt),
                            borderMode=cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    return rot_img
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import math
def shear(angle,x,y):

tangent=math.tan(angle/2)
new_x=round(x-y*tangent)
new_y=y

#shear 2
new_y=round(new_x*math.sin(angle)+new_y)     
#since there is no change in new_x according to the shear matrix

#shear 3
new_x=round(new_x-new_y*tangent)            
#since there is no change in new_y according to the shear matrix

return new_y,new_x




image = np.array(Image.open("test.png"))            
# Load the image
angle=-int(input("Enter the angle :- "))               
# Ask the user to enter the angle of rotation

# Define the most occuring variables
angle=math.radians(angle)                             
#converting degrees to radians
cosine=math.cos(angle)
sine=math.sin(angle)

height=image.shape[0]                                
#define the height of the image
width=image.shape[1]                                    
#define the width of the image

# Define the height and width of the new image that is to be formed
new_height  = round(abs(image.shape[0]*cosine)+abs(image.shape[1]*sine))+1
new_width  = round(abs(image.shape[1]*cosine)+abs(image.shape[0]*sine))+1


output=np.zeros((new_height,new_width,image.shape[2]))
image_copy=output.copy()


# Find the centre of the image about which we have to rotate the image
original_centre_height   = round(((image.shape[0]+1)/2)-1)    
#with respect to the original image
original_centre_width = round(((image.shape[1]+1)/2)-1)   
#with respect to   the original image

# Find the centre of the new image that will be obtained
new_centre_height= round(((new_height+1)/2)-1)        
#with respect to the new image
new_centre_width= round(((new_width+1)/2)-1)          
#with respect to the new image


for i in range(height):
 for j in range(width):
    #co-ordinates of pixel with respect to the centre of original image
    y=image.shape[0]-1-i-original_centre_height                   
    x=image.shape[1]-1-j-original_centre_width 

    #Applying shear Transformation                     
    new_y,new_x=shear(angle,x,y)

   
    new_y=new_centre_height-new_y
    new_x=new_centre_width-new_x
    
    output[new_y,new_x,:]=image[i,j,:]                        

    pil_img=Image.fromarray((output).astype(np.uint8))                       
    pil_img.save("rotated_image.png")
```