# Loop through directory of images and rotate them all x degrees and save to directory

Tags: python, image, opencv, rotation, scipy

I am using Python,Open, Numpy, and Scipy. I have a directory of images that I want to rotate by certain angles. I want to script this. I am using this, [OpenCV Python rotate image by X degrees around specific point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041681/opencv-python-rotate-image-by-x-degrees-around-specific-point/18683594#18683594) but it doesn't seem to pipeline exactly as I envisioned. I get an invalid rotation plan specified, but I don't think that I should be getting this.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

def main():
    outPath = "C:\Miniconda\envs\.."
    path = "C:\Miniconda\envs\out\.."
    for image_to_rotate in os.listdir(path):
        rotated = ndimage.rotate(image_to_rotate, 45)
        fullpath = os.path.join(outPath, rotated)

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to actually read the image file before rotating them. What your current code is doing is just iterating through the names of the files (and directories).

*os.listdir(path)* gives you a list of contents of the folder (basically just the name) and then you need to open these files using the *ndimage.imread()* function.

This should work:

```
from scipy import ndimage, misc
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

def main():
    outPath = "C:\Miniconda\envs\.."
    path = "C:\Miniconda\envs\out\.."

    # iterate through the names of contents of the folder
    for image_path in os.listdir(path):

        # create the full input path and read the file
        input_path = os.path.join(path, image_path)
        image_to_rotate = ndimage.imread(input_path)

        # rotate the image
        rotated = ndimage.rotate(image_to_rotate, 45)

        # create full output path, 'example.jpg' 
        # becomes 'rotate_example.jpg', save the file to disk
        fullpath = os.path.join(outPath, 'rotated_'+image_path)
        misc.imsave(fullpath, rotated)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PS: This way of iterating through the contents of the folder only works if there are only files in the directory and no sub-directories. *os.listdir(path)* will return the names of any files as well as sub-directories.

You can learn how to list only files in a directory from this post: [How to list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)