# How to download and rotate image onsite?

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I use python with BeautifulSoup to download images, but all these images have to rotate 90 degree for view, for save time, I want to rotate it before save to disk, is there any easier way?
By the way, I can download images without rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to download an image -

```
# Import Pillow:
from PIL import Image
import urllib2
from io import StringIO

url = "http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/static/p0201_2.jpg"

# Load the original image:
img = Image.open(urllib2.urlopen(url))

# Counterclockwise 90 degree
img3 = img.rotate(90)
img3.save("img3.jpg")

# Clockwise
img4 = img.rotate(-90)
img4.save("img4.jpg")

# Diable Cropping
img5 = img.rotate(90, expand=True)
img5.save("img5.jpg")
```

So basically you can extract the `src` attributes from the `img` tags and try running the above piece of code. You may have to do some handling where there are Relative URLs used. [concatenating the domain and all]

Comment: Your code is simple! I am using code as below, can you tell me which way is faster to download? Of course, it can be rotated by my method!                          imgData = urllib2.urlopen(urlServer).read()
     output = open(os.path.join(downloadLocationPath, urlLocal), 'wb')
     output.write(imgData)
     output.close()

Comment: I found a problem, the part of image is lost after roated, cause image is not a square, what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried to [rotate the images in their folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42074311/loop-through-directory-of-images-and-rotate-them-all-x-degrees-and-save-to-direc), after they have been downloaded ?

Comment: Thanks again! By the way, the image is created by camera, if light is off the image is black so that such images don't need to be download, how can I check image byte size before download?