# Can not decode QR code using pyzbar with python3

Tags: python, qr-code

I need to decode [this QR Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/090yl.png) using python3, opencv and pyzbar, but I'm not able to get any good result: the script is not able to detect/decode the QR Code.

Here is the code I've used. Is there any good way to improve the recognition?

```
import cv2
from pyzbar import pyzbar

# Image load
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# Read QR
qr_code = pyzbar.decode(image)
print(qr_code)
```

Before applying the QR decoder I also tried to:

Change brightness/contrast:

```
# Change brightness/contrast
image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image, alpha=6, beta=0)
```

Make a binary image:

```
# Make binary image
image[image > 19] = 255
image[image <= 19] = 0
```

Rotate image ([using this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041681/opencv-python-rotate-image-by-x-degrees-around-specific-point)):

```
def rotate_image(image, angle):
    image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return result

image = rotate_image(image, 7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I discovered that the image I was trying to decode is not a QR Code, but a Data Matrix Barcode. Now using [pylibdmtx](https://pypi.org/project/pylibdmtx/) I can decode it.

Comment: pylibdmtx is very slow for me. Did you find an alternative?